# Where do I get a CPU-only version of PyTorch?

Tags: heroku, pytorch

I'm trying to get a basic app running with Flask + PyTorch, and host it on Heroku. However, I run into the issue that the maximum slug size is 500mb on the free version, and PyTorch itself is ~500mb.

After some google searching, someone wrote about finding a cpu-only version of PyTorch, and using that, which is much smaller [here](https://www.codementor.io/akshaysharma17/how-and-why-i-built-an-ml-based-python-api-hosted-on-heroku-j74qbfwn1).

However, I'm pretty lost as to how this is done, and the person didn't document this at all. Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

To be more specific about my problem, I tried installing torch by (as far as I understand), including a requirements.txt which listed torch as a dependency. Current I have: torch==0.4.1. However this doesn't work bc of size.

My question is, do you know what I could write in the requirements file to get the cpu-only version of torch that is smaller, or alternatively, if the requirements.txt doesn't work for this, what I would do instead, to get the cpu version.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Apologies - that wasn't my intent. I'm not exactly trying ask for a recommendation, I'm more trying to ask how to properly use heroku, which I have no experience with. I will update my question.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Per the Pytorch website, you can install `pytorch-cpu` with

```
conda install pytorch-cpu torchvision-cpu -c pytorch
```

You can see from the files on [Anaconda cloud](https://anaconda.org/pytorch/pytorch-cpu/files), that the size varies between 26 and 56MB depending on the OS where you want to install it.

You can get the wheel from `http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/`.
The wheel is 87MB.

You can setup the installation by putting the link to the wheel in the `requirements.txt` file. If you use Python 3.6 on Heroku:

```
http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.4.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

otherwise, for Python 2.7:

```
http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.4.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
```

For example if your requirements are `pytorch-cpu`, `numpy` and `scipy` and you're using Python 3.6, the `requirements.txt` would look like:

```
http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.4.1-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl
numpy
scipy
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand how to install this on my own local machine, but could you be more specific on how to do this on Heroku? Do I edit the requirements.txt in a specific way, or if I directly get the whl file, how do I make Heroku install it for my app?

Comment: updated my answer, you have to include the link to the wheel in the `requirements.txt`

Comment: Is mkl packaged with pytorch cpu whl ?

Comment: could you please tell how to install the pytorch-cpu and torchvision-cpu without using conda. I have created a virtual environment, I want to install it there. (CPU machine, Ubuntu 16.04, NO CUDA support). Thanks.

Comment: try this for Python 3.6 `pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1.post2-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl` and 
`pip3 install torchvision`

Answer (score 33):

As of PyTorch 1.3, PyTorch has changed its API. In order to install CPU version only, use

```
conda install pytorch torchvision cpuonly -c pytorch
```

And, the corresponding wheel files can be downloaded from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html and can be installed using `pip` or use the command similar to the following corresponding to your intended pytorch and torchvision versions

On Linux:

```
pip3 install torch==1.9.0+cpu torchvision==0.10.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

On Windows / Mac:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision
```

**Check the PyTorch's [getting started](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) guide.**

Comment: the getting started guide doesn't say anything about adding `+cpu` to the version. I seems to always automatically install the nvida=* stuff if your local machine has a GPU :(

Answer (score 20):

In 2020, please use the following command if you want to download pytorch-cpu version with pip3 (on Linux and Win):

```
pip3 install torch==1.5.0+cpu torchvision==0.6.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Comment: for the poetry people:
`poetry source add --priority=supplemental torch-stable https://download.pytorch.org/whl/ && poetry add torch==1.5.0+cpu torchvision==0.6.0+cpu`

Answer (score 14):

I'm getting errors for each version from [list of torch stable versions](https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html). like

> `{specific_version} is not a supported wheel on this platform

**Try to put this into your [requirements.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kp6YE.png)**

```js
// requirements.txt

-f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==1.8.1+cpu 
torchvision==0.9.1+cpu
fastai>=2.3.1
ipywidgets
voila
```

Answer (score 11):

Coming to this question after running into the same issue with Heroku's App platform -- slug size *well* over the 500MB limit. The current instruction from the official [PyTorch "Getting Started" page](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) is as follows:

`pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu`

That's for a Linux install, using the latest (1.13.1) stable version, in Python, with pip. Note: the syntax varies based on the system, package manager, language, and preferred build. (See below)

[image: PyTorch Configuration Applet]

Answer (score 3):

You can use pip to download the latest CPU-only pytorch wheel directly from the pytorch.org website:

```
pip install torch --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the size of the libs, when you use an application locally you can use the GPU resources, as you will not use this on the server, use the following code in requirements.txt:

```
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torch==1.11.0+cpu
--find-links https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
torchvision==0.12.0+cpu
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install stable pytorch=1.4.0 cpu version using requirements.txt then specify direct download http link...
So that pip will download and install directly...

```
http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.4.0%2Bcpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

Alternatively if using terminal or cmd

```
torch==1.4.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

For more versions, visit
https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html and choose version as per your requirement (windows, linux, mac version all can be seen in the link)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to solve this problem only using the `requirements.txt`, put the following into your `requirements.txt`:

```
--index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu
--extra-index-url https://pypi.org/simple
torch==2.2.1
Flask==3.0.2
```

Basically it tells pip to first try to lookup every package in `https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu`, which will give you the CPU-only version of torch. For every other package (i.e. Flask) it will fallback to the default index.

Answer (score -2):

The correct answer is to search for it on the Pytorch website, here: https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/

They have a complete list of all of the previous versions, as well as the pip syntax to use for each one (including CPU-only versions).