# What's means undefined symbol: cublasLtHSHMatmulAlgoInit, version libcublasLt.so.11

Tags: python, spacy

I am using SpaCy and SpaCy Stanza in Jupyter notebook with python 3, and I get the following error

```
OSError: /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/lib/../../nvidia/cublas/lib/libcublas.so.11: undefined symbol: cublasLtHSHMatmulAlgoInit, version libcublasLt.so.11
```

can anybody help me?

I tried update

```
pip install --user nvidia-pyindexpip install --user nvidia-tensorflow
```

but the error remains, How can I fix it?

Comment: If you have Torch 1.13, try downgrading to 1.12. If that's not the issue, please show your code, the output of `pip freeze`, `spacy info`, etc.

Comment: In case you need cpu-only version of pytorch follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75485213/7991462) answer

Answer (score 18):

I fix this error by adding the directory into `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment  variable.

Like this:

```bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/nvidia/cublas/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, Adenialzz! I am trying to add the variable as you wrote, but I have the following error: "  File "/tmp/ipykernel_17/23200807.py", line 1
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

Answer (score 5):

You can find your path by

```
pip show nvidia-cudnn
```

then

```
Name: nvidia-cudnn
Version: 8.2.0.51
Summary: cuDNN runtime libraries
Home-page: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone
Author: Nvidia CUDA Installer Team
Author-email: cuda_installer@nvidia.com
License: NVIDIA Proprietary Software
Location: /home/yourname/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: wheel, setuptools
Required-by: nvidia-tensorrt
```

**Location:** shown where your package installed.

In this case,adding following path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` solve my problem

```
/home/yourname/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nvidia/cublas/lib/
```

Comment: This gives me ` WARNING: Package(s) not found: nvidia-cudnn `

Comment: @Ananda same for me, the message was `[...] This package is hosted on NVIDIA Python Package Index. This package can be installed as: $ pip install nvidia-pyindex $ pip install nvidia-cudnn` the first one worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just as other answers show, setting nvidia-cublas path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH will solve the problem.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/xxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nvidia/cublas/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

You can use following commands to find your path of nvidia-cublas:

```
$ pip list |grep nvidia
nvidia-cublas-cu11       11.10.3.66
nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu11   11.7.99
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11 11.7.99
nvidia-cudnn-cu11        8.5.0.96

$ pip show nvidia-cublas-cu11 
Name: nvidia-cublas-cu11
Version: 11.10.3.66
Summary: CUBLAS native runtime libraries
Home-page: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-zone
Author: Nvidia CUDA Installer Team
Author-email: cuda_installer@nvidia.com
License: NVIDIA Proprietary Software
Location: /xxx/lib/python3.8/site-packages
Requires: setuptools, wheel
Required-by: nvidia-cudnn-cu11, torch
```