# Pytorch lightweight cpu-only version

Tags: optimization, pytorch, computer-vision

I have an issue gathering my project for Docker image. With PyTorch it takes about 1.5 Gb of disk space.
I tried to install cpu-only version of torch. However, despite downloading the proper version, pycharm installs a full-scale package (circa 800 Mb vs 174Mb).

The relevant code on the screen.
[requirements.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XEC5.png)

I used `pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt` command after modifiyng my requirements as in this post: [Where do I get a CPU-only version of PyTorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51730880/where-do-i-get-a-cpu-only-version-of-pytorch)

I presume the issue is the cache, but I dont know the proper way to clean it (and which cache to clean exactly).

Also, if someone can explain or link me the proper way to optimize ML apps for deploy in docker I would be extremely grateful. 1.5 Gb for quite a simple detection app is a bit rough)

Comment: You can convert your PyTorch model to a portable format like ONNX, then use the `onnx-runtime` to run the model